Encrypting IDs in URLs using Laravel's Crypt facade results in "The payload is invalid" error
I'm trying to encrypt the IDs of items when displayed in the URL of my Laravel application.
For example, instead of displaying:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/assessments/1/edit 
I want to encrypt the ID so it looks something like:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/assessments/encrypted-id/edit 
I am using Laravel's Crypt facade for encryption. Here is the method in my controller:
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;

public function edit($id) {
    $assessment = Assessment::findOrFail(Crypt::decrypt($id));
    return view('directories.assessments.edit', compact('assessment', 'id'));
}

In my Blade file, I am encrypting the ID like this:
<form action="{{ route('assessments.update', Crypt::encrypt($assessment->id)) }}" method="POST">
Despite this, I am encountering an error stating "The payload is invalid." I have tried generating a new app key and ensured that I am importing use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;.
Steps Taken:

Generated a new application key using php artisan key:generate.

Confirmed that use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt; is imported correctly.


Error Message:
The payload is invalid.
Can someone help me understand why this error is occurring and how to properly encrypt and decrypt IDs in Laravel URLs?

Why do you need to do that in the first place?

For security reasons, do you have a better suggestion?

What is the security problem?

Encrypting IDs can help prevent users from easily guessing and altering the URLs to access other records. For example, if a user sees http://127.0.0.1:8000/assessments/1/edit , they might try http://127.0.0.1:8000/assessments/2/edit to access another item. Encrypting the ID makes this much more difficult.

There should be a check server-side to make sure the user has the right to access the item.

Use UUIDS instead of ids?

@brombeer how do i go about using this

https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/eloquent#uuid-and-ulid-keys

hashids would work since you already have ids

As lagbox suggests, it would be much simpler for you to use the hasids package - or change to use UUID keys. But this should not be your only line of defence to prevent unauthorised access to an assessment. Read the Laravel docs about authorisation.

Sequential IDs on their own are not a security issue... Open access to the Routes associated with those IDs is a security issue. There are plenty of ways to handle this properly, but obfuscating the URLs (i.e. by encrypting/decrypting) is "security by obscurity", which on the surface is more secure, but in reality really isn't all that secure... As suggested, you need to use some kind mechanism to ensure only the people who are supposed to access those URLs can access them. Generally, a simple Role/Permissions thing is enough, or even checking the ID associated with the record, etc.

Sidenote, I can't reproduce your issue... If I do Crypt::encrypt('1'), then use that value in a URL, like /{encrypted-id}/test, the code dd(Crypt::decrypt($id)); properly shows the value of '1'... Additionally, using the code route('test', ['id' => Crypt::encrypt('2')]) and navigating to that URL shows the ID of '2', as expected.

I have the code on my GitHub, You can check this repo if you would like to contribute https://github.com/aaron-muti-420/skillharbor-open

I got the solution i had to encrypt the id on my frontend like (Crypt:: encrypt ->id) and then decrypt it in my controller (Crypt:: decrypt)
